# Pesquisa no mongodb por texto?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-web-api

Eu quero criar uma busca nos itens que estou listando, quero filtrar de acordo com o o que usuario passar em um campo tipo o google.com digita clica em pesquisar e retornar os resultados que contem aquele texto, mas eu quero que busque tudo que contem aquele texto mesmo que tenho coisas antes e mesmo que tenho coisas depois sem case sensitive.

Estou usando API Web com o ASP.NET Core e o MongoDB

Eu tentei códigos assim, mas são código mas para cmd, eu quero usar na minha classe de service que faz a persistência dos dados

```
        //return _items.Find<Item>(item => item.Name == LIKE keyword).FirstOrDefault();
        //return _items.Find<Item>(item => item.Name == itemIn.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        //return _items.find({$text: {$search: "Sorriso"} });
```

Para me conectar ao mongo estou usando essa class

```
using desafio.Models;
```

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace desafio.Services
{
    public class ItemService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection _items;

```
    public ItemService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("DesafioDb"));
        var database = client.GetDatabase("DesafioDb");
        _items = database.GetCollection<Item>("Items");
    }

    public List<Item> Get()
    {
        return _items.Find(item => true).ToList();
    }

    public Item Get(string id)
    {
        return _items.Find<Item>(item => item.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public List<Item> Buscar(string keyword)
    {
        //Colocar verificação se keyword for vazinho buscar o metodo get que retorna tudo ou alaramr que não foi encontrado

        Item itemIn = new Item();
        itemIn.Name = keyword;

        return _items.Find(item => item.Name == itemIn.Name).ToList();
    }

    public Item Create(Item item)
    {
        _items.InsertOne(item);
        return item;
    }

    public void Update(string id, Item itemIn)
    {
        _items.ReplaceOne(item => item.Id == id, itemIn);
    }

    public void Remove(Item itemIn)
    {
        _items.DeleteOne(item => item.Id == itemIn.Id);
    }

    public void Remove(string id)
    {
        _items.DeleteOne(item => item.Id == id);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: o que você está usando para fazer conexão com o mongo?

Comment: Eu atualizei o código da uma olhada ai coloquei a minha classe de ItemService

Comment: sua entidade item tá com as anotações certinho?

Comment: Sim ta tudo funcionando direitinho mas no metodo Buscar eu só busco se apalavra estiver certinha, eu quero fazer aquelas buscar tipo no sql que não importa o que vem antes ou depois

Answer (score 2):

Que contenham o texto é preciso usar o famoso like de bancos relacionais. 
segue exemplos em mongo.

```
inserts = 

db.users.insert({name: 'paulo'});

db.users.insert({name: 'patric'})

db.users.insert({name: 'pedro'})

pesquisas =

db.users.find({name: /a/})  //like '%a%'
saída: paulo, **patric**

db.users.find({name: /^pa/}) //like 'pa%' 
saída: **paulo, patric**

db.users.find({name: /ro$/}) //like '%ro'
saída: **pedro**

//return _items.find({$text: {$search: /Sorriso/} }); que contenham a palavra  Sorriso
```

Comment: Mas esses comando só funcionam no shell, eles não funcionam na classe que implemento o método de busca